# Share Internet from static ip ethernet cable to wifi (Home Gateway)

Tags: wifi, ethernet, lan

I have an Ethernet cable coming from the wall with a static IP address for internet access and I am using it for my PC. I have a home gateway (HG532s) with 1x ADSL port and 4x Ethernet ports and WLAN and I can see its SSID from my laptop. I would like to set one of the LAN ports to have the static IP coming from the wall where as others could connect to the internet through WIFI or other available LAN ports. Is this possible?

Kind regards

Comment: (you will have to use router) and how it is related to coding issue?

Comment: I thought stack overflow is for all kind of technical issues... where should I post such issues for future reference?

Comment: Stack OverFlow is for programming related questions - your problem is better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try This ...
Access your home gateway console using telnet/ssh .
do ifconfig , you will find all listed interfaces.
next to give ip of your subnet by typing
ifconfig eth0(your LAN interface) 192.168.1.X(your staic IP subnet X is of your choice) up

Use it .

cheers